# PHP paths are doubling on running script in localhost

Tags: php, html, sql, web

I have a website containing different php files and sql database. It is a content management website. I am trying to test it on localhost using XAMPP server on this path: 
localhost/avs
avs is the folder in which index and all other files are located. 
When I start the website, it shows a splash screen but doesn't go to further links because links doubles as: 
Enter BUtton: **localhost/avs changes** to **localhost/avs/localhost/avs**

Following is the code for configs.paths.php in which I inserted the localhost paths, [Only 01 place BASE_URL I changed, all the rest is default]:

```
<?php
defined('_VALID') or die('Restricted Access!');
$config = array();
$config

['BASE_URL'] = 'localhost/avs';
$config['RELATIVE'] = '';
$config['BASE_DIR'] = 

dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$config['TMP_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR']. '/tmp';
$config['LOG_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR']. '/tmp/logs';
$config['IMG_DIR'] = 

$config['BASE_DIR']. '/images';
$config['IMG_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL']. 

'/images';
$config['PHO_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR']. '/media/users';
$config

['PHO_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL']. '/media/users';
$config['VDO_DIR'] = $config

['BASE_DIR']. '/media/videos/vid';
$config['VDO_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL']. 

'/media/videos/vid';
$config['FLVDO_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR']. 

'/media/videos/flv';
$config['FLVDO_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL']. 

'/media/videos/flv';
$config['TMB_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR']. 

'/media/videos/tmb';
$config['TMB_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL']. 

'/media/videos/tmb';

$config['HD_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR'].'/media/videos/hd';
$config['HD_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL'].'/media/videos/hd';
$config

['IPHONE_DIR'] = $config['BASE_DIR'].'/media/videos/iphone';
$config

['IPHONE_URL'] = $config['BASE_URL'].'/media/videos/iphone';        
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
# Comment the 2 lines below if the server returns 500 errors!
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Uncomment following lines if you want to use image caching!
#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#  ExpiresActive On
#  ExpiresDefault A1209600
#  ExpiresByType text/html A1
#</IfModule>

# Uncomment following lines if Apache doesnt support MultiViews!
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Uncomment the 2 lines below if you are using www.domain.com
    # as the baseurl for the site and users access your site 
    # via domain.com (THIS IS REQUIRED FOR JQUERY TO WORK)

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# Edit below lines and set to
# ErrorDocument CODE /RELATIVE/error.php
# If the script is installed in the default document
# root then relative is null.
#ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
#ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
#ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Other information: the sql database is linked successfully (tested)

Comment: Please check if htaccess is there? is there any table where you saving urls? could you please share screen-shot for more details?

Comment: @PramodKharade Sir I edited the post and added code of htaccess that is in my folder of avs script

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure since you haven't put an example of how you use the URLs that you define, but it seems that you are trying to construct the absolute URLs to different pages, and the problem is that you have defined as the base URL as:

```
$config['BASE_URL'] = 'localhost/avs'
```

including the host name but *without* including the `http://`, so if you do something like this:

```
<img scr="<?php echo $config['IMG_URL']?>/image.jpg">
```

you are getting a *relative URL* instead an absolute one, and any URL included in `http://localhost/avs/index.php` will point to `http://localhost/avs/localhost/avs/[anything]`, because relative URLs are relative to the path of the file in which they are included.

In other words, without including the `http://` or `https://` the host name is interpreted as another directory of the path.

You have two options to solve this:

- Convert all URLs in absolute URLs including the `http://` in the base URL:

  ```
  $config['BASE_URL'] = 'http://localhost/avs'
  ```
- Use URLs relative to the root directory (without including the host name):

  ```
  $config['BASE_URL'] = '/avs'
  ```